# How to test if Angular Material Dialog is open

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-test

I am writing a unit test to check whether or not a function call opened the a Material dialog element. I am getting False, whereas the expected result is True. The component function is:

x.component.ts

```
openCartDialog(): void {
        this.dialog.open(CartComponent);
        this.isCartDialogOpen = true;
}
```

And my x.component.spec.ts file has the following code and test:

```
export class DialogMock {
    open(): void {
        return;
    }
}

beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [MainPageComponent, CartComponent, ConfirmButtonComponent],
        imports: [RouterTestingModule, HttpClientModule, MatTabsModule, MatDialogModule],
        providers: [
            { provider: MatDialog, useClass: DialogMock },
        ],
    }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MainPageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});


it('should open the cart dialog', () => {
       component.openCartDialog();
       expect(component.isCartDialogOpen).toBeTrue();
});
```

I think the problem lays in my beforeEach() where the CartComponent is not instantialized properly. The Cart component also uses other components in its template...I only included ConfirmButtonComponent in this code, but there are more.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe the error comes from ```component.isUserGuideOpen``` when in it should be ```component.isCartDialogOpen```

Comment: I made a typo copying my code into Stack overflow. Both variables have the same name

Comment: I think that by testing if the component calls the dialog.open() is a better way to test, then to actually test if dialog.open actually opened the dialog, this way you are testing this class independent from other classes. 

You can mock/spy on dialog.open and check if it has been called / called with parameters etc.

Comment: This makes a lot of sence, thank you. It also simplifies other tests I have.

Comment: Opening a dialog returns a reference to the dialog. Save that somewhere and call on the dialog ```getState()``` which evaluates to true if its open.